# Moving Mott Transition Tunnels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

I have a question on moving tunnels. Let's assume you have a wrapped semiconductor by a piezolectric material that creates a series of staggered mott transitions along the conductor. Each mott transition is set such that it allows a tunnel. The tunnels then move at a given speed. Given parameters, how is resistance affected?

What happens when each tunnel moves at a very high speed along the conductor? Say 0.9c?